# How to find out if a item has been selected in a POSTed IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have this in my view (pseudo code):

```
for(int i=0;i<10; i++) 
{
    @Html.CheckBox("Article[" + i + "].ArticleID")
    @Html.Textbox("Article[" + i + "].Quantity")
}
```

This is sent to a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<Article> Article) 
{
}
```

Now the question is, how do I know (in my controller) which articles were checked? Because it returns all the form fields, not just the ones that are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the code above does work as planned. The checkboxes that are not checked return 0, so I can filter those out.